# Why is my included layout's tag returning null?

Tags: android, android-layout, include

Using the below layouts, `getView(R.id.included).getView(R.id.text_view)` evaluates to `null`.  If I surround the `TextView` in a `LinearLayout` the problem disappears.  What's going on here?

**`layout.xml`**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <include android:id="@+id/included"
      layout="@layout/included" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**`included.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/text_view"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

`<include>` isn't exactly [well documented](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html).

Tor Norbye [wrote](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36918#c3):

The `<include>` tag is not a real view, so `findByView` will not find it. The `@id` attribute (and any other attributes you've set on the include tag) gets applied on the root tag of the included layout instead. So your `activity.getView(R.id.included1)` should in fact be the `<TextView>` itself.