# findViewById() from another layout not updating data

Tags: android, layout, findviewbyid

I have mainActivity, that has xml that include another xml . Both activitymain layout has a button, and the included layout has another button. Both should display into the main activity. 
Now , i need to change text of both button. I can get reference to first button by findviewByID , and it works. for the second button that is into the second layout, i get view by inflating the layout, It gets properly refence to the view and the findviewbyID gets reference to this button. But when changing the text, it does not change.

activityMain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<Button android:id="@+id/buttonvvv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
  <include
            layout="@layout/layouttest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

layouttest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonaaa"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
---Mainactivity.java----------------------------------
 import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  View view=LayoutInflater.from(getApplication()).inflate(R.layout.layouttest, null);

        Button b =(Button)  findViewById(R.id.buttonvvv);
        Button bb =(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonaaa);
         b.setText("ssssssss");
         bb.setText("ssssssss");

    }
```

Results

```
buttonvvv text is updated and becomes ssssssss
buttonaaa text is Not updated and still Button
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to inflate the layout, just find it like:

```
LinearLayout layout =(LinearLayout)  findViewById(R.id.layouttest);
```

and then

```
Button bb =(Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.buttonaaa);
```

Comment: Thanks forpas for support.

Answer (score 2):

No need for inflating the included layout, you can just `findViewById` like you did with `b button`. **It's already included with `activity_main.xml` layout**

**Replace this:**

```
    View view=LayoutInflater.from(getApplication()).inflate(R.layout.layouttest, null);
    Button b =(Button)  findViewById(R.id.buttonvvv);
    Button bb =(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonaaa);
    b.setText("ssssssss");
    bb.setText("ssssssss");
```

**With :**

```
    Button b =(Button)  findViewById(R.id.buttonvvv);
    Button bb =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonaaa);
    b.setText("ssssssss");
    bb.setText("ssssssss");
```

**From Doc[`include`](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts):**

> The root View should be exactly how you'd like it to appear in each
>   layout to which you add this layout.

**BTW,** check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12221874/1283715)

Comment: same issue...  buttonvvv text is updated and becomes ssssssss buttonaaa text is Not updated and still Button

Comment: @waleed.makarem Check my updated answer, No need to inflate `layout_test.xml`, **It's already included with `activity_main.xml` layout**

Comment: @KhaledLela nice job!